# Redis key not removed even after Resque job completes successfully

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, redis, resque, jobs

Here is my scenario, i'm using [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque) to queue a job in redis, the usual way its done in ROR. The format of my key looks something like this (as per my namespace convention)

```
"resque:lock:Jobs::XYZ::SomeCreator-{:my_ids=>[101]}"
```

The job runs successfully to completition. But the key still exists in redis. For a certain flow, i need to queue and execute the job again for the same parameters (the key will essentially be same). But seems like the job does not get queued.

My guess is that since the key already exists in Redis, it does not queue the job again.

Questions:

Is this behavior of resque normal (not removing the key after successful completition)?

If Yes, how should i tackle this scenario (as per best practices)?

If No, can you help me understand what is going wrong?

Answer (score 2):

After a couple of hours of debugging, finally this is the observed behavior:

- I was creating the job and passing the options (parameters) with `symbolized keys` which when created the Redis key for the same job with symbolized param in the key.

Example:

`Jobs::Abc::SomeJobCreator.create({:some_ids => [101]})` would create the **"redis key"** as `"resque:lock:Jobs::Abc::SomeJobCreator.create({:some_ids => [101]})"` (Notice the key being a symbol in the key)

- Now when the **after_perform_hook** executes, it tries to remove the Redis Key but it searches the key with Stringified keys: `"resque:lock:Jobs::Abc::SomeJobCreator-({\"some_ids\"=>[101]}"` Which obviously won't be found, as the key in Redis has symbolized params in key.
- To fix this issue i had to change the calls to job creation in the code and use stringified params like this: `Jobs::Abc::SomeJobCreator.create({'some_ids' => [101]})`. This works fine.

Not sure if this has anything to do with the version of Resque. Since its a old codebase i haven't yet updated the version. Its currently at **Resque v1.25.2**